# Can't get into BIOS or boot from usb (Samsung NP900X3E)

Tags: windows-8, boot, laptop, usb, bios

I can not go into bios or boot mode through recovery, I've tried f2 and once I press it it goes into window 8 recovery.

Answer (score 0):

try Hold the <kbd>F2</kbd> key, before you start the laptop. Also you can try to use <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Badr Bellaj but it still does not work  ;(

Comment: Normally when samauns PCs boot they show in the boot screen which button to press to GI to the setup(bios) I don't have the same laptop but check the first screen or try keeping press ESC button otherwise F4

Comment: Yes exactly but once i press either buttons it does not work unfortunately what could this mean?

Comment: maybe use an external keybord your buttons may be not working